# How can api in Mobx be both method invocation and decorate method?

Tags: javascript, decorator, mobx

How can API in Mobx be both common method invocation and decorate method? such as observable. Is it using the duck type to detect the parameters passed when calling the API?

Answer (score 0):

Using `observable(value)` and `@observable classProperty = value` is not equal. The first is just a method invocation that export from MobX and the second is syntactic sugar for `extendObservable(this, { property: value })`. they are not same.